# Puppet node not found, default node not used

Tags: puppet

I'm using environments on my master and in both (test and prod). The `environment.conf` for both environments (identical in both environments) contains:

```
modulepath = ./modules:../common/modules
manifest = ./main.pp
```

The `main.pp` file (also identical) contains:

```
include(lookup('classes', { 'merge' => 'unique' }))
node default { }
```

I currently have an ENC shell script that is literally one line and just outputs the environment to use for a node, which doesn't really seem necessary since it's also in `puppet.conf`, so I am trying to remove the ENC. Running `puppet agent` on the master works fine without the ENC configured. However, when I try to run `puppet agent` on a new node, without the ENC configured on the master, I get this response:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Failed when searching for node [...]: You must set the 'external_nodes' parameter to use the external node terminus

Even it I comment out the `default` node in both environments, I still get this error. Even when specifying the environment on the `puppet agent` command line and/or in `[master]` within `puppet.conf` on the new node, I get the same error.

I do use Hiera, and there is a node file for Hiera for the new node, though that doesn't provide a node definition (as far as I know), so I don't know if it gets that far. I would expect it to use the `default` node and get classes from Hiera.

I guess my question is why is it giving me this error, shouldn't it use the default node?

**Update 1:**

Here is the `puppet.conf` that gets distributed:

```
[agent]
server = puppet-prod.foo.com

[main]
environment = prod

[master]
dns_alt_names = puppet-prod,puppet-prod.foo.com
```

These are the lines I removed to get rid of the ENC:

```
external_nodes = /usr/local/bin/puppet-node-classifier
node_terminus = exec
trusted_server_facts = true
```

Comment: Welp, it looks like maybe Puppet is caching some configuration information and doesn't reload it all when it says it does. Restarting it worked (I was running with `--no-daemonize --verbose` to debug).

Comment: Since the problem was solved by restarting the master, I'm voting to close as irreproducable.

Comment: Technically it's reproducible, just start Puppet with the ENC config, then change the config without restarting. However I'm fine with closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this case, this was a pretty silly problem; all I needed to do was restart the Puppet master process.

I was updating the configuration files, and it was logging that it was reloading the entire configuration when I touched the main `puppet.conf` file, however it apparently wasn't refreshing the ENC configuration.

Amazing how much time I wasted on this before turning it off and on again...

Answer (score 1):

> You must set the 'external_nodes' parameter to use the external node terminus

This suggests that the ENC isn't fully de-configured.

Check for a line such as this in puppet.conf and either remove or comment it out:

```
node_terminus = exec
```

Comment: Right, I used to have that, but I removed that line also. I'll update with the whole file.